# Overriding equals/hashCode on cross referencing classes in Java causes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, equals, stack-overflow, cross-reference

I have two classes that represent two different database entities. Their relationship is 1:m in db and it is represented in class structures something like this:

```
public class Company {

    private List<Employee> employees;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}

public class Employee {

    private Company company;

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

}
```

Now I want to override equals/hashCode on these classes. Eclipse generates the following code for me:

```
public class Company {

    private List<Employee> employees;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((employees == null) ? 0 : employees.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Company other = (Company) obj;
        if (employees == null) {
            if (other.employees != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!employees.equals(other.employees))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

public class Employee {

    private Company company;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((company == null) ? 0 : company.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (company == null) {
            if (other.company != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!company.equals(other.company))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

If I run the following test:

```
public class EqualsTest {

    @Test
    public void testEquals() {

        Company company1 = new Company();
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();

        employee1.setCompany(company1);
        company1.setEmployees(Arrays.asList(employee1));

        Company company2 = new Company();
        Employee employee2 = new Employee();

        employee2.setCompany(company2);
        company2.setEmployees(Arrays.asList(employee2));

        assertThat(company1, is(company2));
    }

}
```

I expect it to pass because both company1 and company2 have equal lists of employees, but it fails with StackOverflowError:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.<init>(AbstractList.java:318)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.<init>(AbstractList.java:318)
    at java.util.AbstractList$ListItr.<init>(AbstractList.java:377)
    at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:315)
    at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:284)
    at java.util.AbstractList.equals(AbstractList.java:502)
    at com.test.Company.equals(Company.java:37)
    at com.test.Employee.equals(Employee.java:35)
    at java.util.AbstractList.equals(AbstractList.java:507)
    at com.test.Company.equals(Company.java:37)
    at com.test.Employee.equals(Employee.java:35)
    at java.util.AbstractList.equals(AbstractList.java:507)
    at com.test.Company.equals(Company.java:37)
    at com.test.Employee.equals(Employee.java:35)
        ...
```

I understand that the reason for this failure is cross reference in classes and thus equals/hashCode methods. But how should I implement equals/hashCode to avoid infinitive recursion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is now, the identity of a company is defined solely by its employees. Likewise, the identity of an employee is defined solely by its company. Do you see how that leads to a mutual logical dependency?

You need to break that logical dependency in your code. How would you logically uniquely identify a company and an employee? Typically you'd do this with some sort of meaningful unique identifier: a name (string), a number (int/long), or some similar combination of primitive fields.

Comment: Thanks, MДΓΓ БДLL. There are other fields on those classes (simle strings like company name, employee name, etc) and they are included in the equals/hashCode methods. I just omitted them in the question as they don't cause any issues, cross reference that's what's causing problems.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you should omit the company's employees from the `Company#hashCode()` and `Company#equals()` methods. An employee can be defined by the company she works for, but a company is not (uniquely, anyway) defined by its employees.

Comment: As I commented on schtever answer that will cause two companies with the same name but different employees to be equal, that is not right.

Comment: Then an employee should not be uniquely defined by the company they work for! Like I said, you've got to choose where to break the logical loop. It is up to you to decide what uniquely defines your entities. You could introduce a separate/independent identifier field for a company if the name is not sufficient to uniquely specify a company. You can't have things both ways: you need to choose to start somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, MДΓΓ БДLL. I didn't think about single (or composite) identifier that would signal equality of two objects of the same type. For some reason I thought I need to use *all* the fields on the class.  Maybe auto-generation of these methods by Eclipse needs to be more flexible. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Eclipse's method auto-generation is _very_ flexible. It allows you to choose which fields to include (and thus, which to omit) from the generated `#equals()` and `#hashCode()` methods. What else do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Imho there are 2 versions available. I assume company should be the "leading" class, storing the employees.

1. version: In the employee equals, use the "==" to check for object equality on company (not very nice)
2. version: assign your company a unique ID and compare that only that company ID in employee equals

hth

Comment: Thanks, phloc. I'll go for option #2.

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare the list of employees within the Company.equals method.  Are there other attributes of Company that are meaningful and could be used to perform the comparison within equals, like a name?  Or Stock Symbol?

Comment: There are other simple fields on those classes. Your suggestion will cause two companies with the same name but different employees to be equal, that is not right.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why that is not right?  Will you have a situation where two companies with the same name will in fact be different entities?

Comment: Thanks, schtever. As I commented in the accepted answer I didn't think about single (or composite) identifier that would signal equality of two objects of the same type. For some reason I thought I need to use all the fields on the class for that.

Answer (score 1):

You have inadvertently set up a recursive dependency between `Company` and `Employee`.  The `Company#hashCode()` method needs to compute the individual hashcodes of every Employee, and the `Employee#hashCode()` method depends on the Company's hashcode, leading to an infinite recursion.

A company object's hashcode should not depend on the employees in it.  The hash code is in some sense the "identity" of the object, which shouldn't change when a new employee is added to it.  Same for Employee.  The Employee's identity shouldn't change just because he/she moves to a different company.

You'll have to redefine those methods in terms of some meaningful identity attribute.  Your code doesn't show it, but both `Company` and `Employee` must have some other member variables, such as a name.  Base the hashCode and equals implementations on that attribute.

Comment: I want two companies with the same lists of employees to be considered equal. How is that possible with comparing just identity attributes.

Comment: Don't use `equals`, write a separate `Comparator` for that purpose.