# Java : StackOverflow while Overriding equals method

Tags: java

I have 2 objects : User & Image. The User contain an Image (profile) and the Image contain a User (creator).

I want to override the method equals but i get stuck with a StackOverflow error in it.

User :

```
public class User{

    private int id;
    private Image profilePicture;

    // [...] A lot of other varibales

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {

        User user = null;

        if (object instanceof User)
            user = (User) object;
        else
            return false;

        return (   id == user.getId()
                && profilePicture.equals(user.getProfilePicture())
                // [...] testing others variables
                );
    }
```

Image :

```
public class Image{

    private int id;
    private User creator;

    // [...] A lot of other varibales

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {

        Image image = null;

        if (object instanceof Image)
            image = (Image) object;
        else
            return false;


        return (id == image.getId()
                && creator.equals(image.getCreator())
                // [...] A lot of other varibales
               );
    }
}
```

What is the best way to resolve these kind of conflits ? Thanks

### EDIT

**I do understand why i am getting the stackoverflow error**.

My question is about the differents ways possible to resolve the conflit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918732/overriding-equals-hashcode-on-cross-referencing-classes-in-java-causes-stackover

Comment: do you really need to compare the images in the equals method? Can't you just compare user ids? (same comment for the other equals)

Comment: Looks like your two equal methods call each other continuously, which is why you are getting a stack overflow

Comment: I understand why i am getting the stackoverflow. What i want to know is the best ways to deal with this kind of problems :)

Comment: I could, and i think i will use comparison with id. But i want to know if there is other method.

Comment: @assylias Thx, exactly the same question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recursively calling `.equals` in the `User` and `Image` class. Try to implement the `.equals` method in a different way. `.equals` in the `User` class calls `.equals` in the `Image` class and vice versa which results in a `stackoverflow`.

Comment: I do understand why i get the error. I want to know about the differents ways to resolve this kind of conflits :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that what exactly `equals` represents is up to you to define. For some kind of objects "all fields are the same value" is the correct thing to do.

For many objects that have IDs, comparing just those IDs is the correct thing to do. In your case, defining User.equals() as "two User objects are equal if their ids are the dame" would solve the concrete problem (if you do change that, remember that `hashCode()` needs to be changed to not use any data that `equals()` doesn't use).

Whether or not that fits in how exactly you use `equals()` is a separate question that can't be answered with the data you've given.

Comment: I did think about the method "id == id -> object == object" but i wanted the values to be part of the comparison. Using the hashcode AND the id could be a good solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this problem due to the recursive call of `.equals()` method.

You are calling `.equals()` of `Image` from `User` and again `.equals()` of User from `Image` which is again calling `.equals()` of `Image` and will keep calling until stack overflows and you get that exception.

In order to resolve this problem, you need to remove `.equals()` from either of them.

In my point of view, you should remove it from both because while checking equality of `Image`, you should check equality of `Image` itself, not the `User` and same is applied to vice versa.